# Facing issue in after Tridion Installation

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

[image]I need some help on a SDL Tridion Installation.

We are done with installation of SDL Tridion followin the instructions provided in installation guide.

We are able to launch the site with Content Manager Administrator (Installation Owner).
But when we click on "Administration" section in the UI am not getting any options that an administrator can do i.e., not able to create Users, Target Types, Groups etc… I can’t even find the list of users that are existing in the system.

When I click on Show Users am getting an error.

Please help me out in fixing this...

Comment: What version of Tridion did you install? Did you check event viewer for any possible errors?

Comment: Sounds like your 'Administrator' user is not a sysadmin in Tridion. Can you look in the Trustees table and check if the 'is_privileged' column (or something similar) has the value 1 for your admin user?

Comment: I have installed Tridion 2011.

Comment: I checked in [Tridion_cm].[dbo].[TRUSTEES] table in DB, and found an admin user in the table with Description as "Content Management Administrator". there is a column named PRIVILEGE which is set to 1.

Comment: When the installer runs it asks for the Admin user account.  That account is added to the Trustees table and is the only account you can use after installing.  The next step is to create normal users.  I would check the Event Viewer and see if any errors exist there and also try a different browser.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to install Tridion Content Manager again in Repair mode. Once done I have made some changes in Binding setting of IIS, and now am perform all the admin operations.

My Issue is solved now. Thanks everyone who responded and tried helping you.

-Aswan

Answer (score 2):

You mention you are able to access the Administration section of the UI, which indicates that your user indeed has the correct (Administration) rights.

You also mention the list of users is empty, which is also correct, you have just installed so there are no visible users. The Administrator user and the MTSUser account which were created during installation are both hidden since they are protected users.

As to adding a new user, you first need to get the list of users (even though it is empty) before you can add a new user to that list. So from the Users menu, choose Show Users, and that should enable the New User option which you can select then. Same thing goes for the Target Types, Publication Targets, Protocol Schemas and most of the other options in the ribbon toolbar there.

[image: Show Users command]

Comment: Bart, Thanks for the response. I too accept with your point about MTSUser and Administrator. I tried creating user in Tridion, When I click on show users system it erroring out. "Invalid URI: cme:accmng"

Comment: okay looking at that update I'm stumped, I have no clue what that error is about, but it looks like something is completely wrong, if you have tried clearing browser cache, then maybe its worth trying a repair of that installation, consider doing it again from scratch or last option contact Custom Support

Comment: Thanks Bart, We ran the Installer in repair mode and tried its working fine now. Thanks once again for your intrest in guiding me. :)

Comment: You're welcome Aswani, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.